# Select All Combinations of Values From Multiple Tables, Keeping Max of Column A For Any Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I'm building a result table that draws from multiple tables in my database and includes a Distinct. It works until I add the Case/When to add in a multiplier to the result if a condition is met.

(Yes, this is a Pokémon related tool I'm building, and yes, I am an utter man-child).

This is the code I've currently got:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.Name as 'Fast Move'
      ,(CASE WHEN Pokemon_Types_And_Moves.Primary_Type = f.Type
                  THEN (f.Damage * 1.2)
             WHEN Pokemon_Types_And_Moves.Secondary_Type = f.Type
                  THEN (f.Damage * 1.2)
             ELSE f.Damage END) as 'Damage'
      ,f.DPS as 'Fast Move DPS'
      ,c.Name as 'Charged Move'
      ,c.Damage as 'Charged Move Damage'
      ,c.DPS as 'Charged Move DPS'
      ,((f.Cooldown * CEIL(c.Energy_Required / f.Energy_Generated)) + c.Time) as 'Full Cycle Time'
      ,((f.damage * CEIL(c.Energy_Required / f.Energy_Generated)) + c.Damage) as 'Full Cycle Damage'
      ,ROUND(((f.damage * CEIL(c.Energy_Required / f.Energy_Generated)) + c.Damage) / ((f.Cooldown * CEIL(c.Energy_Required / f.Energy_Generated)) + c.Time), 2) as 'Full Cycle DPS'
FROM Fast_Moves f, Charged_Moves c, Pokemon_Types_And_Moves
WHERE (f.Name IN (SELECT Fast_Move_1
                  FROM Pokemon_Types_And_Moves
                  WHERE Pokemon_Name = 'Beedrill')
    OR f.NAME IN (SELECT Fast_Move_2
                  FROM Pokemon_Types_And_Moves
                  WHERE Pokemon_Name = 'Beedrill')
    OR f.NAME IN (SELECT Fast_Move_3
                  FROM Pokemon_Types_And_Moves
                  WHERE Pokemon_Name = 'Beedrill'))
AND (c.Name IN (SELECT Charged_Move_1
                FROM Pokemon_Types_And_Moves
                WHERE Pokemon_Name = 'Beedrill')
  OR c.NAME IN (SELECT Charged_Move_2
                FROM Pokemon_Types_And_Moves
                WHERE Pokemon_Name = 'Beedrill')
  OR c.NAME IN (SELECT Charged_Move_3
                FROM Pokemon_Types_And_Moves
                WHERE Pokemon_Name = 'Beedrill'))
ORDER BY f.Name, c.Name
```

It is returning a duplicate of every line, except one line has the "normal" damage result and one line has the desired multiplied result.

I'm sure the issue is that it is returning two lines from the "Case" statement near the start of the query, but I just can't work out how to stop it.

I've tried incorporating MAX clauses etc but nothing has worked so far.

Current results:
(Not allowed to add pictures yet as I'm a new user, but the results are basically:

```
Fast Move    Damage      Charged Move     Charged Move Damage
Bug Bite     5           Aerial Ace       10
Bug Bite     6           Aerial Ace       12
```

And then the same for every other combination. As you can see, Beedrill is receiving the 1.2 multiplier and so the first line is redundant. (Hope this makes sense!)

Comment: I can see here that you have used 3 tables but there is no join condition. Probably that might be reason for the duplicates.

Comment: If no one was allowed to add pictures, SO would be an immeasurably better place.

Comment: Perhaps you might think about splitting Pokemon_Types_And_Moves into two tables --> Pokemon_Move <--(and)--> Pokemon_Move_Type. I feel like you are stuffing too much information, column wise, into the database table(s).